# Coinlist exchange API authentication - Python

Tags: python, cryptography, exchange-server, coinbase-api

For the past month I've been trying to understand coinlist API (https://coinlist.co) since there is no API wrapper available it's been a hard task. I could figure it out that their API docs are really similar to coinbase exchange, and tried to extrapolate but with no success.

```
import json, hmac, hashlib, time, requests
from requests.auth import AuthBase

# Before implementation, set environmental variables with the names API_KEY and API_SECRET
API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
API_SECRET = 'xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=='

# Create custom authentication for Coinlist API
class CoinlistWalletAuth(AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, api_key, secret_key):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.secret_key = secret_key

    def __call__(self, request):
        timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
        message = timestamp + request.method + request.path_url + (request.body or '')
        signature = hmac.new(self.secret_key, message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

        request.headers.update({
            'CL-ACCESS-SIGN': signature,
            'CL-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
            'CL-ACCESS-KEY': self.api_key,
        })
        return request
```

```
auth = CoinlistWalletAuth(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
#Test1 - Fetching account balance
response = requests.get('https://trade-api.coinlist.co/v1/accounts', auth=auth)
```

I am getting this *TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'* when calling for the response.

Docs say - You must base64-encode the signature (the output of the sha256 HMAC). Why is it failing?

Answer (score 0):

#### Two things:

[TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html#hmac.new)

> hmac.new(key, msg=None, digestmod='')
>
> Return a new hmac object. key is a bytes or bytearray object giving the secret key. (...)

```
import base64
...
secret_key_as_bytes = base64.b64decode(self.secret_key, altchars=None)
```

[The CL-ACCESS-SIG header is generated by creating a sha256 HMAC using the base64-decoded secret key on the prehash string timestamp + HTTP method + path + body (where '+' represents string concatenation) and **base64-encode the output**.](https://trade-docs.coinlist.co/?javascript--nodejs#api-key-authentication)

```
digest = hmac.new(secret_key_as_bytes, message, hashlib.sha256).digest()
signature = str(base64.b64encode(digest))
```

Answer (score 0):

wish it's not too late
hmac.new()
function need the key argument to be bytes,so:

```
byte_key = bytes(self.secret_key, 'UTF-8')  # key.encode() would also work in this case
```

but it's no done yet, if you go with this, you would get

> TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
> to fix this , your message should be encoded.

```
message = message.encode()


h = hmac.new(byte_key, message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

now it's done.
Howerver I got 400. sad.

I found someone have done this:
https://gist.github.com/badmofo/d109fbc447fea64d99e5ca58bdf53d7b